# IoC, MVC4 Web API & HttpParameterBinding/ParameterBindingAttribute

Tags: inversion-of-control, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 4 RTM Web API.  I have a controller action with a parameter that I'd like to populate via custom model binding.  To achieve this, I created a class that derives from `System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpParameterBinding` that sets the value of this parameter.  I then created an attribute class that derives from `System.Web.Http.ParameterBindingAttribute` which I use to decorate the parameter on my controller action.

This is all working great, my `HttpParameterBinding` class is populating the action parameter correctly.  The problem I have is that my custom parameter binding class has a dependency that I'd like resolved via my IoC container (Unity).  Is there a way to override how Web API creates `HttpParameterBinding` instances so that I can build up my custom binding class dependency from Unity?  I was able to do something similar for a filter attribute by creating a custom filter provider that uses Unity's `BuildUp` method to populate dependencies, however I'm not seeing anything similar for Web API's `HttpParameterBindings`.

Answer (score 0):

In general: to use IoC / Unity in the Web API you need to set it up seperately.

Try downloading the nuget package Unity.WebApi and see if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for trying but unfortunately your response isn't terribly helpful.  From what I can gather on the Unity.Webpi package, it is simply an IDependencyResolver implementation, which does not address my problem.

Comment: Hmm sorry.. can you maybe post a code sample of what you're trying todo..? That might clarify the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: [Parameter Binding in WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

It walks through a couple different options from Converters to Binders to BinderProviders.  It sounds like you may be able to write a custom `ModelBinderProvider` which knows how to provide your dependency.  If that isn't high enough in the chain you can look at replacing the default `IActionValueBinder` service.  It's a `DefaultActionValueBinder` instance, which you can extend or simply re-implement.

I also highly recommend downloading the WebAPI source code, as it's been an incredible help for these issues as I've run into them.  Here's the [WebAPI source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest).  I recommend downloading it so you can open it in VS for easy navigation.

Feel free to check out [FlitBit](https://fbcore.codeplex.com/) too (It's very modular, don't let the number of packages scare you off)!  I'm working on a WebAPI package for supporting FlitBit, specifically FlitBit.IoC and FlitBit.Dto.  I'll add an update if I work out my IoC issue, since it's very similar to yours.

Comment: I just realized that this was from 2012 rather than last week.  Feel free to share if you resolved your issue.  Or mark my response as an answer if it's in line with your solution.  Hopefully it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET WebAPI has an extension point where you can specify the binding rules:

```cs
public static void SetParameterBindingRules(HttpConfiguration config, ILogger logger)
{
  config.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, descriptor => descriptor.GetCustomAttributes<FromBodyAndUriAttribute>().Any() ? new BodyAndUriParameterBinding(descriptor, logger) : null);
}
```

The snippet above injects custom parameter binding if a parameter has the `FromBodyAndUriAttribute` attribute. And the `HttpParameterBinding` has a dependency on a logger. This extension point can be called in App_Start after initializing your container.

Full code:

```cs
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace WebApi
{
 public partial class Startup
 {
  public void Configuration(Owin.IAppBuilder app)
  {
   var container = ConfigureContainer();
   var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();

   GlobalConfiguration.Configure(
    config =>
    {
     config.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, descriptor => descriptor.GetCustomAttributes<FromBodyAndUriAttribute>().Any()
      ? new BodyAndUriParameterBinding(descriptor, logger)
      : null);
    });
  }
 }
}
```